# I need an approach to find out the color codes available in an image in each div using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Approach to find out the RGB values for an image in a webapp. I have not got any proper approach yet. Not getting the same .

Comment: There's not enough of a description of the problem here for us to help you.  For starters, what are "color codes available in an image"?  Are you talking about all the different RGB values in a JPEG image?

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00. Yes i need RGB values. I need it for every pixel. Is it possible to do so ? Right now i can find it on click or on mouse hover.

Comment: Well, there are a number of libraries for node.js that can encode or decode JPEG image data.  Here's one: [jpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js).  Search NPM for others.